# Problems changing date format of date as string

Tags: excel, function, date, formulas, excel-2013

I am currently trying to convert `yyyymmdd` type of date to a `ddmmyyy` format.

- I've tried using DATE function and something like this:

  `=DATE(LEFT(A3;4);MID(A3;5;3);RIGHT(A3;7))`

  Original date for this function is `20120401` but the formula returns: `16.12.2104`.
- I've tried using functions YEAR, MONTH and DAY instead of LEFT, MID and RIGHT but that's not the right way.
- I also tried using DATEVALUE but since Excel probably doesn't recognize `yyyymmdd` as a date, it gives me a #VALUE! error.
- I've found a couple of solutions for SQL but it isn't my strong side yet - and this should be achievable easily in Excel.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Err ... till now this little comment didnt even show up. Well this one works for me, now I understand where Ive made mistake. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can post this as a regular answer, I can give you props ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `=DATE(LEFT(A3;4);MID(A3;5;3);RIGHT(A3;7))` to 20120401 in A3 is effectively to reassemble the component characters as below on the left:

[image]

These effectively become converted as on the right.

The solution was simply to exclude the digits highlighted red with:
`=DATE(LEFT(A3;4);MID(A3;5;2);RIGHT(A3;2))`
but the locale might have been a factor and when dealing with date serial numbers and/or what appears to be a date but is a string various other issues might have been involved.

Comment: Thanks again bro, very useful. Im on 8 rep now. As soon as I hit 15 I will give you vote up here ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

**=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))**

Comment: Ye Ive tried this one and some tutorials suggest this formula. I dont know about older Excels but in 2013 version the function shows that I have to use semicolons like this: DATE(year; month; day) i.e. DATE(left; mid; right) where LEFT, MID and RIGHT are (text; [num_chars]).

Comment: Ye I understand that but as I said Ive tried the version with commas aswell but since Excel shows that I should use semicolon it wont let me use this suggested formula cause if Im not gonna use semicolon after defining LEFT, Excel thinks Im still defining LEFT while Im on MID/RIGHT already. Same thing happens when I use semicolons after each function (LEFT, MID, RIGHT) but not in brackets-there is a problem with that formula.So far best result was from using correct form with semicolons as Ive posted in my question.But the output was wrong.Any other type without those semicolons isnt working.